Project of a passband filter in CST
I'm trying to project a metasurface passband filter in CST, I need help with the design of the unit cell. I tried with FR4 as substrate and a PEC grid on top of it. I need the transmission range between 2-6 GHz and it has to behave as a PEC until 18 GHz.
The problem is that to work at such low frequencies I need high periodicity but than I have problems with grating lobes in the range between 6-18 GHz. I'm trying to change the parameters but I cannot find a solution.
First form I've tried

